# how to execute a Stored Procedure via zend framework

Tags: sql-server-2008, zend-framework, stored-procedures

i have a SP in a stored .sql file.
is there any way so i can execte it with ZF? i dont have any (?) in it.

my codes are:

```
USE [PIS]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[version]    Script Date: 11/24/2011 12:47:09 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[version]') AND     type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[version]
GO

USE [PIS]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[version]    Script Date: 11/24/2011 12:47:09             ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[version]
with encryption

as
select '2.2.213'
GO
```

by the way im using sqlsrv database driver & SQLSERVER 2008 & PHP5